# How To Access HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT In Python

Tags: python

am trying to add a registry key under root like so

```
 reg = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, "jpegfile", 0, _winreg.KEY_SET_VALUE)
```

but i am reciving this error

```
E:\hello.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\hello.py", line 22, in <module>
define_action_on(".jpeg", "Upload", "\"E:\\python\\python.exe\" \"E:\\hello.
py\" \"%1\"", title="Upload to imgur with python")
File "E:\hello.py", line 16, in define_action_on
reg = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, "jpegfile", 0, _winreg.KEY_
SET_VALUE)
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied
```

Comment: Try running as Administrator

Comment: I figured it out the administrator had some how lost ability to write to that registry not sure why.

Comment: This isn't a forum - we don't edit titles to day SOLVED. drum should write an answer which you can then accept.

Comment: Thank You for letting me know but down voting the question is harsh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your code as Administrator.